Creating a formula in the script that changes rows like auto-fill does
I have some coding experience but not much with this language. I am trying to create a script that will automatically copy a formula down column H, the only problem is that it is referencing that same row in column F. This is the code I have so far, the "F2" is where my problem is. Otherwise it runs like a champ.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the used range on the current sheet.
    const currentSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table = workbook.getTables()[0];
    // Get the values of the used range.
    let range = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
    let rangeValues = range.getValues();
 // set number of rows and iterate
    let rowCount = range.getRowCount();
    for (let i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    // The column at index 7 is column "8" or "H" in the worksheet.
    if (rangeValues[i][7] != 0) {
        selectedSheet.getCell(i, 7).setFormula("= IF(COUNTIF(F2, \"*ASST*\"),\"ASST\",\"NOT LISTED\")");
    }}}

I've tried to create a variable, use (i,5), and getCell, getRange. I finally came back to check that it still ran. For any of those I might have been missing an important part of the syntax to make it work. Any assistance or suggestions is greatly appreciated!!

Is this something you are looking for?
selectedSheet.getCell(i, 7).setFormula(=IF(COUNTIF(F${i + 1}, "*ASST*"), "ASST", "NOT LISTED"));

Set formulas for Col H in the table all at once.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the used range on the current sheet.
    const currentSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table = workbook.getTables()[0];
    // Get the values of the used range.
    let getCol7 = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getColumn(7)
    getCol7.setFormula(`=IF(COUNTIF(F2,"*ASST*"),"ASST","NOT LISTED")`)
}


Since the table may not start at cell A1, the script below is more reliable for locating the desired column by its name.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the used range on the current sheet.
    const currentSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table = workbook.getTables()[0];
    // Get the values of the used range.
    const targetCol = "Col8" // Header of the 8th col in the table, modify as needed
    const colRange = table.getColumnByName(targetCol);
    if(colRange){
        // get the 8th col w/o header row
        const rngCol8 = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getColumn(colRange.getIndex());
        // get the first data cell in the 6th col
        const rngCellCol6 = rngCol8.getCell(0, 0).getOffsetRange(0, -2).getAddress().split("!")[1];
        // apply formulas
        rngCol8.setFormula(`=IF(COUNTIF(${rngCellCol6},"*ASST*"),"ASST","NOT LISTED")`)
    }
}



Thank you! I cannot seem to get either to work. This is a side project so I don't always have time to devote. I am trying the top one because my column 8 does not have a title, I will need to add that to the code at some point probably. The first option keeps giving me this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal')" Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

It means the data source on worksheet is NOT a Excel Table. Please select the data range (include header row) and press Ctrl+T to create a Table. Or follow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664. Sharing a screenshot with dummy data is helpful to understand the layout of your worksheet.
